# Create components with circular relationships using Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm implementing a finite-state machine, with each class representing a state. Each state knows which other states it can transition to, and this naturally leads to circular relationships. (See the [State Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)).

For this simplified example I'm creating two components, where the first component has a reference to the second component, and the second component has a reference to the first.

The problem is that the Windsor framework is correctly setting the references for the first created component, but not setting the references for the second:

Here are the two components:

```cs
// DefaultMouseHandler knows about NewLineMouseHandler
public class DefaultMouseHandler : MouseHandler
{
    public DefaultMouseHandler()
    {
    }

    public NewLineMouseHandler NewLineMouseHandler
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    internal override MouseHandler LeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        return this.NewLineMouseHandler;
    }
}


// NewLineMouseHandler knows about DefaultMouseHandler
public class NewLineMouseHandler : MouseHandler
{
    public NewLineMouseHandler()
    {
    }

    public DefaultMouseHandler DefaultMouseHandler
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    internal override MouseHandler LeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        return this.DefaultMouseHandler;
    }
}
```

I then register the components as so:

```cs
_windsorContainer.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                                 .BasedOn<MouseHandler>()
                         );
```

But when I first attempt to create the `DefaultMouseHandler`:

- The `DefaultMouseHandler` is constructed
- The `NewLineMouseHandler` is constructed
- The `NewLineMouseHandler` is set on the `DefaultMouseHandler`

But the `DefaultMouseHandler` is NOT set on the `NewLineMouseHandler`.

Can this be considered a defect in Castle Windsor?

What's the best way to have the two components referencing each other, without either component being aware of the Windsor container?

Comment: Such circular dependencies looks like a bad design idea, perhaps you can introduce third entity which would decouple relations?

Comment: If I understood design idea right - it might worth injecting DefaultHandler instance in the `DefaultMouseHandler()` constructor like `DefaultMouseHandler(MouseHandler defaultInstance)` and exposing property to more generic `public MouseHandler DefaultMouseHandlerInstance`, also it make sense using interfaces for such sings so relations would be less coupled, I would add at least interface for `IMouseHandler`

Comment: @sll - This is an implementation of a State Machine, which naturally leads to circular coupling. I've added a longer introduction thanks to your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've come up with is to use the [TypedFactoryFacility](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx?NoRedirect=1&NS=Windsor).

This allows objects to be created as they are needed, so we don't have the complications of them all being dependent upon one another at initialization time.

```c#
public interface IMouseHandlerFactory
{
    T CreateHandler<T>() where T : MouseHandler;
}

// In the registration code
_windsorContainer.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
_windsorContainer.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                               .BasedOn<MouseHandler>(),
                           Component.For<IMouseHandlerFactory>()
                                    .AsFactory()
                          );

// The base class
public abstract class MouseHandler
{
    // Every mousehandler will create at least one other mouse handler
    // This is the factory that they will use for mouse handling creation
    // The property will be automatically set by the DI container
    public IMouseHandlerFactory MouseHandlerFactory { get; set; }

    // Methods the concrete implementations will override
    internal virtual MouseHandler LeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) { return this; }
    internal virtual MouseHandler LeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) { return this; }
}   

// The implementations
public class DefaultMouseHandler : MouseHandler
{
    internal override MouseHandler LeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        return this.MouseHandlerFactory.CreateHandler<NewLineMouseHandler>();
    }
}

public class NewLineMouseHandler : MouseHandler
{
    internal override MouseHandler LeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        return this.MouseHandlerFactory.CreateHandler<DefaultMouseHandler>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sll that it might be a sign the design could be improved. On the other hand there are valid reasons for doing what you're doing. If you never resolve `NewLineMouseHandler` and it's only used as dependency of `NewLineMouseHandler`, just set the dependency manually:

```cs
windsor.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                    .BasedOn<MouseHandler>()
                    .ConfigureFor<NewLineMouseHandler>(
                        h => h.OnCreate(
                            c =>
                                {
                                    var @default = (DefaultMouseHandler) c;
                                    @default.NewLineMouseHandler.DefaultMouseHandler = @default;
                                }))
    );
```

Comment: The coupling between the components is going to continually change with future development, so I don't wish to explicitly set this in the registration - too much extra maintenance. The TypedFactory facility seems to be the way to go for this one, but I'd be interested in your thoughts on this.