# Is using TypedFactoryFacility wrong?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have the following factory installed in my IoC container:

```
// Factory for late-binding scenarios
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IServiceFactory>()
        .AsFactory()
);
```

Where `IServiceFactory` is:

```
public interface IServiceFactory
{
    T Create<T>();
    void Release(object service);
}
```

And then my controller looks something like this:

```
public class PostsController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IServiceFactory serviceFactory;

    private LinkService linkService
    {
        get { return serviceFactory.Create<LinkService>(); }
    }

    public PostsController(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        if (serviceFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceFactory");
        }
        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }
```

The whole point being, even when `LinkService` has `PerWebRequest` lifestyle, I might not always need it, therefore, injecting it directly seems wrong to me.

Though, the question that pops to mind now is: am I using the container as a service locator here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `T` is unbounded, which it is in this case, you are. You are putting knowledge of the type to create in the receiving class. This configuration is best left to the class which has the responsibility to setup your container. In Castle 3.0, you have the option to use `Lazy<T>` to defer resolution, which you could easily do here:

```
 public PostsController(Lazy<ILinkService> linkService) 
 { 
     if (linkService == null) 
     { 
         throw new ArgumentNullException("linkService"); 
     } 

     this.linkService = linkService; 
 }
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I wanted, elegant and concise.

Comment: See: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx#Added_support_for_Lazy__components_3

Comment: Taking a dependency on Lazy<T> is essentially a Leaky Abstraction. What purpose does it serve? Lazy initialization? If that's the case, a Virtual Proxy provides a cleaner design: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/ComposeObjectGraphsWithConfidence.aspx

Comment: It's not `Lazy<T>` - it's `Lazy<ILinkService>`.

Comment: The argument is not against the use of `T` - it's against the use of `Lazy`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are [using the container as a Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryOrServiceLocator.aspx).

Comment: Interesting blog entries. However, I couldn't see in the blog how DO you deal with the situation when you actually have to do lazy instantiation? For example: I had [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088534/create-components-with-circular-relationships-using-castle-windsor) involving circular references, and the only solution I could come up with was to use the TypedFactory.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the TypedFactory. The problem is how it's used in this particular case (with an unbounded `T`).